# Understanding Memory Management in JavaScript, Mozilla

Tags: javascript, object, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm new to `JavaScript` and trying to understand the memory management related to objects using this Mozilla reference: [MDN Memory Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management).

I am following an example, but having issues in understanding the references.

```
var o = { 
  a: {
    b:2
  }
}; 
// 2 objects are created. One is referenced by the other as one of its property.
// The other is referenced by virtue of being assigned to the 'o' variable.
// Obviously, none can be garbage-collected

   var o2 = o; // the 'o2' variable is the second thing that 
                // has a reference to the object
    o = 1;      // now, the object that was originally in 'o' has a unique reference
                // embodied by the 'o2' variable

    var oa = o2.a; // reference to 'a' property of the object.
                   // This object has now 2 references: one as a property, 
                   // the other as the 'oa' variable

    o2 = "yo"; // The object that was originally in 'o' has now zero
               // references to it. It can be garbage-collected.
               // However what was its 'a' property is still referenced by 
               // the 'oa' variable, so it cannot be free'd

    oa = null; // what was the 'a' property of the object originally in o 
               // has zero references to it. It can be garbage collected.
```

I got confused by terms like **this object**, **one is referenced by the other**, 2 objects are created - **for what? 'o' & 'a'?**, that has a reference to the object - **which object?**

Can someone rephrase the comments above with the actual object names, please?

It may consider as a *spoonfeeding* question but let me know if it's not worth to ask this question. I'll delete it.

Comment: Objects don't have names; that's kind of the point. There are either variables (or object properties) referencing an object or there aren't.

Comment: JavaScript has literal notation for objects. These objects can have other objects as their properties.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of a crummy explanation. I'll give you a rough edition.

```
var o = { 
  a: {
    b:2
  }
}; 
// 2 objects are created. One (the value of the property named "a")
// is referenced by the other (the value of the variable named "o")
// as its property.
// The other (the value of the variable named "o")
// is referenced by virtue of being assigned to the 'o' variable.
// Obviously (maybe to the author...), none can be garbage-collected

var o2 = o; // the 'o2' variable now also
            // has a reference to the object (the value of the variable "o")

o = 1;      // "o" now refers to something else and "o2" is the only variable
            // referring to the original "o" object.

var oa = o2.a; // reference to the 'a' property of the "o2" object.

o2 = "yo"; // The object that was originally in 'o' has now zero
           // references to it, but
           // the object's 'a' property is still referenced by 
           // the 'oa' variable, so the "o2" object cannot yet
           // be GC'ed.

oa = null; // The object now has zero references to it, so it can be
           // garbage collected.
```